# iterm, unable to fork, too many processes?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

[image: Unable to fork]

I wasn't able to open new iterm window due to the message, the photo above. Even though t definitely looks running too many processes,I think mac wasn't running too many processes. I've checked activity monitor but couldn't find any difference between normal situation.

I solved this with rebooting but wanna know what the exact problem and how to check that. If anybody has any idea, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
> ulimit -u
```

to see max **u**ser processes or

```
> ulimit -a
```

to see **a**ll user limits.